# How to do MongoDB query with JavaScript expression in Java code , like in Mongo shell

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb

1.
I know how to **query with JavaScript expression in Mongo shell**
( collection name is `resource_phys`. field name is `val` which defined as **String** type and contains only **numeric value** ) :

```js
//in Mongo shell:
var query1 = ("Number(this.val)>-1 && Number(this.val)<3")
db.resource_phys.find(query1)
//result found
```

2.
Now, I want to **do the same thing in Java code** but cannot find any API to support JavaScript. I solicit your help to give some hints.

3.P.s.
If the field `val` is numeric type, I am aware of using operator `$gt` and `$lt` :

```
//in Java codes:
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("resource_phys");
DBObject query2 = new BasicDBObject("val",new BasicDBObject("$gt",-1).append("lt",3));
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query2);
//result got in cursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of query you are doing in the shell is actually just a shortcut form of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. So you would translate like this:

```
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
            "$where",
            "Number(this.val)>-1 && Number(this.val)<3"
    );
```

Please note the documentation though, as running JavaScript is not a good idea for performance. You really should convert your strings to be actual numeric values.

Comment: Amazing! Awesome!Fabulous!Thanks! ---I did tried using $where but not worked, but now your code works fine.so strange! And I did know the performance issue but just leave it right now...Thanks again!